# How to connect to the wallet in the built-in browser of Phantom Wallet

Tags: phantom

I want to use this string of code to call the connection in the built-in browser of the mobile Phantom wallet, but found that it does not work, so what can I do to connect the phantom on the mobile phone?

```
> const getProvider = () => {   if ('phantom' in window) {
>     const provider = window.phantom?.solana;
> 
>     if (provider?.isPhantom) {
>       return provider;
>     }   }
> 
>   window.open('https://phantom.app/', '_blank'); };
```